# how to change a file name when saving it?

Tags: c#, file-io, binary

I edited a binary file in my code and I want to save it. I am using the method WriteAllBytes(string SavingPath, array). However, how do I code so that it has a specific name? Also, out of curiosity, what name does C# give when saving it without any specific name?

Thanks

Comment: Please, share your code

Comment: Re: "what name does C# give when saving it without any specific name?" See the docs: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=netframework-4.8 There are various exceptions which are thrown if the path is not valid.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The filename must be specified in the `SavingPath` parameter. Example:

```
byte[] fileContent = ...; // your content

string filename = "test.txt";
string path = @"c:\temp";
string fullPath = Path.Combine(path, filename); // this will result in c:\temp\test.txt

File.WriteAllBytes(fullPath, fileContent);
```

Answer (score 3):

> how do I code so that it has a specific name?

You pass a particular file name to `WriteAllBytes`. For example:

```
File.WriteAllBytes(@"Path\To\MyFile.bin", array);
```

---

> what name does C# give when saving it without any specific name?

You have to pass a filename, so this is impossible. If you pass a filename which is invalid, the method will throw an exception. From [the docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.io.file.writeallbytes?view=netframework-4.8):

> **Exceptions**
>
> `ArgumentException`
>
> `path` is a zero-length string, contains only white space, or contains one or more invalid characters as defined by InvalidPathChars.
>
> `ArgumentNullException`
>
> `path` is `null` or the byte array is empty.
>
> `PathTooLongException`
>
> The specified path, file name, or both exceed the system-defined maximum length.
>
> `DirectoryNotFoundException`
>
> The specified path is invalid (for example, it is on an unmapped drive).

Answer (score 0):

Command ***File.WriteAllBytes(string SavingPath, byte[ ] array)*** will do what you want. 
SavingPath can be for example ***"D:\\SampleFolder\\MyFile.txt"***

Here, ***MyFile.txt*** is file name. 
Since I dont know what exactly you want to accomplish, this is just idea. You must add some logic.

Answer (score 0):

```
File.WriteAllBytes(string path, byte[] bytes);
```

> However, how do I code so that it has a specific name?

The `path` *is* the filename.

```
string path = @"C:Users\Name\Desktop\Filename.txt";
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 };

File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes);
```

This code saves a file named `Filename.txt` to the Desktop. If this file already exists, its contents will be overwritten.

> Also, out of curiosity, what name does C# give when saving it without any specific name?

If you try saving without a filename, an exception is going to occur.

```
// No filename provided.
string path = @"C:Users\Name\Desktop";
byte[] bytes = new byte[] { 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20, 0x20 };

try
{
    // This will throw an exception.
    File.WriteAllBytes(path, bytes); 
}
catch (Exception)
{
    // Error message that says its not a valid path.
    Console.WriteLine(e.Message);
}
```